# A question regarding nets of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, nets

I am trying to understand the following theorem from [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.2404.pdf) paper

[image: this]

I understand the first part of the proof. Basically we are adding in $F_\alpha$ all matrices with entries from $\{-2, -2+\frac{\sqrt{\alpha}}{10n},\cdots, 2-\frac{\sqrt{\alpha}}{10n},2\}$. I don't understand the cardinality bound as stated in the lemma. Can anyone please help me understand this?

Thanks